A thought crime?
What happens if I come to police and tell them I want to steal some goods from supermarket?
Same if I tell them I want to kill someone (without threatening a specific person).
Let's also assume I am tested by psychiatrist and considered fine.

I'm not sure how a psychiatrist could think you are "fine" if not only do you want to commit crimes, but you think it is a good idea to inform the police about those crimes beforehand! Anyway, "what would happen" isn't really a question about the law, it's a question about police procedure (they would probably add you to a watchlist of some sort, maybe they would try to get a warrant to find evidence of your plans). If you're asking whether the actual behaviour in your question (telling the police you intend to commit crimes) is against the law, then you should spell that out clearly.

Need to consider there is a big difference in the potential risks if you say you want to shoplift from a supermarket and if you want to kill someone. For the second one there are going to be a lot of issues if you actually kill someone and the police didn't do anything to stop it after they are informed of your intent.

There is no such thing as a "thought crime", and it isn't illegal to "want" something, but at some point you risk crossing a line into actively planning and conspiracy to commit a crime.  A better question might ask about that specific threshold.  Because the sarcastic answer is that the police will "want" to arrest you.  P.S. If you did go to the police to tell them this then your psychiatrist probably needs to re-evaluate you.  Because you definitely aren't "fine"...

@kaya3 "if not only do you want to commit crimes" - it's absolutely normal to think about actions that can be considered as crimes. Hate, passion, desire to possess, desire to hurt someone - normal human impulses. Please, do not answer the question connected with human psychology if have zero clue about it.

Well, please don't read the first half of the first sentence of my comment and ignore the rest. The part where the hypothetical person goes to the police to inform them of their intentions is what makes me question their sanity.

There is a difference between thought crimes, speech crimes, and crimes involving speech.
In most reasonable jurisdictions, you can think about crimes as long as you want. By talking about them, you are making a threat and the threat may in itself be a crime. Or it may be protected by the freedom of speech, if it is sufficiently vague.

Consider various gangster rappers or narcocorridos. They glorify a criminal lifestyle and talk about crimes, these forms of speech are usually protected.
Consider the stereotypical "nice shop, it would be a pity if it burned down." Speaking those words is extortion.
germany has §126 StGB, disturbing the public order by threatening crimes or pretending that crimes have been threatened. Details would depends on the details, as usual.


Maybe I am overthinking it but isn't there a difference between writing/singing a song about various crimes and telling police that you want to commit those crimes?

@JoeW I think o.m. was rather talking about the glorification of the crimes that they actually (most likely) also did. They might sing about how cool it is to consume certain substances or to get involved in rape.

@JoeW, the German §126 centers on disturbing the peace through threats, there are others about wasting police time through false alerts. Songs might qualify under disturbing the peace.

They will try to find out whether you really intend to do that. If so, and if they find some evidence (e.g. you just bought a gun), you might be charged for an attempted crime.
If they find that you are making a fool of them, you'll also be in trouble, because fooling the police and thus causing needless but time-consuming investigations is an offense in most jurisdictions, as well.

I would emphasis "intend" rather than "really". Wanting to do something is very different from intending to do so. I may want to assassinate the President of Russia, but I don't intend to do anything about it because I am not capable of doing so. I also want to be able to read mind, but I don't intend to do so, because I'm not telepathic.

@ohwilleke Agreed, changed.

I think the second sentence is mostly wrong. You're free to tell the police what you want to do, and they're free to ignore your or investigate.

@bdb484 I don't know how exactly they would react, but they would need to be doing something about it. Whether they do a five-minute interrogation or a five-month investigation is up to them, yes. But in either case they need to come to a conclusion whether to drop the case or charge you for whatever they found.

Right, but what are they going to charge you with? Neither desiring to commit a crime nor reporting that desire is a crime in most jurisdictions, I imagine.

@bdb484 Desiring probably not, but maybe I am confessing that I intended to get rid of my wife?

Maybe, but that's not pretty distinct from what we're talking about here.

canada
We cannot predict how police will deal with that information.
But you have not described a crime known in Canadian law.

Making a threat is a crime. It is not just describing a crime.
The police have discretion and do not have to arrest. They could arrest you though. Your question seems to assume the threat is not a crime when it is widely known it is.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
